# Swing vs AWT vs SWT!?

Tags: awt, java, swt, swing

Что лучше использовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте Swing. AWT - это самая базовая UI библиотека. Она используется для рисования примитивов и создания примитивных объектов (окно). Она имеет некоторый ограниченный набор компонентов, но они довольно примитивные и не стоит на них рассчитывать.

Что же до SWT, то она неплохая, но у неё плохая переносимость и на Linux она жутко выглядит.

Comment: смотря на каком линуксе и чем запускать ;)

Answer (score 0):

Swing, AWT, SWT - во многом похожи (2D vs 2D). Используйте то, что Вам удобнее.